# A tasklist tool for matlab

Tags: matlab, todo, tasklist

In Visual Studio there is a tool called TaskList, which searches the code for TODO comments, compiles a list of them, and lets you go to a TODO item in the code by clicking on it in the list.  Is there an equivalent tool in Matlab?  Is there even a convention for TODO comments in Matlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[What’s on my TODO list?](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2008/03/17/whats-on-my-todo-list/) is a post on *'Mike on the MATLAB Desktop'*
concerning TODO lists.

Comment: That certainly beats my %fixthislaterwhenyouhavemoretime comments!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>There is no such tool in the MATLAB Editor, and no formal convention for the format of TODO comments.</strike>

**EDIT:** Apparently, there *is* [such a tool on the MATLAB Desktop](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2008/03/17/whats-on-my-todo-list/) (as the other answers point out), but I guess it's not the easiest thing to find as I've somehow managed to miss it for years. One drawback (which the MathWorks appears to be planning to fix sometime in the future) is that you can only search individual directories.

In addition, there are a couple utilities submitted by users on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) that you may want to check out which appear to perform similar functions:

- [Filegrep](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4397-filegrep) by [Brett Shoelson](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/911)
- [parseTags](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26352-parsetags-matlab-tag-parser) by [Alexander Reinhold](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/80592)
- [searchtext](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15121-searchtext) by [Kevin](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/28293)

You could try these out and compare them to the built-in MATLAB TODO report generator, or even use them as a guide to create your own TaskList-like functionality.

Comment: It turns out there is such a tool!

Answer (score 2):

Recent version of MATLAB can generate a report of TODO/FIXME. Check out [this post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2008/03/17/whats-on-my-todo-list/), or read the relevant section in the documentation: [Identifying Files with Reminder Annotations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f9-6232.html#f9-6114)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a **newer version of MATLAB** and can't find the directory reports-drop down as explained by zellus

> You can get to this report using the directory reports-drop down in the Current Directory Browser
>   http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2008/03/17/whats-on-my-todo-list/,

you need to navigate to the **context menu** of the *Current Folder* view as shown in the following screenshot: (due to not sufficient reputation, I unfortunately cannot show the screenshot here directly)

[Screenshot of the TODO/FIXME Report location](http://s14.directupload.net/images/141029/2ncvuqhx.png)